# How to configure a custom bootstrap bucket name in cdk.json

Tags: aws-cdk

Let's say I have bootstrapped using `cdk bootstrap --bootstrap-bucket-name foo --toolkit-stack-name cdk-foo --qualifier foo-backnd`. How do I update my `cdk.json` to include the custom bucket name? I have found documentation for `@aws-cdk/core:bootstrapQualifier` but nothing for the bucket name.

Hitting this: `[100%] fail: No bucket named 'xyz-123456789-us-east-1'. Is account 123456789 bootstrapped?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using **custom CDK Qualifier** and **custom S3 Bucket Name** for CDK Bootstrap and **I don't need to have the S3 Bucket Name in `cdk.json`** *(I mean, it's not supposed to be there)*.

When you check the [CDK Bootstrapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/bootstrapping.html) Documentation, there are 2 relevant Sections to your Question:

**1) Customizing bootstrapping** – which says:

> There are two ways to customize the bootstrapping resources.
>
> - Use command-line parameters with the cdk bootstrap command. This lets you modify a few aspects of the template.
> - Modify the default bootstrap template and deploy it yourself. This gives you unlimited control over the bootstrap resources.

Based on your Question, you're using the first one – CLI parameters. I just want to point out here, that **you don't have to modify the default bootstrap template in order to use custom S3 Bucket Name for CDK assets**.

Take a look at the next section just below the first one:

**2) Stack synthesizers** – which says:

> Your AWS CDK app needs to know about the bootstrapping resources available to it in order to successfully synthesize a stack that can be deployed.

So you've changed some defaults by using CLI parameters and you have to set those changes "somewhere" before deploying the CDK App.

**Custom `qualifier` can be set either in `cdk.json` or in the Synthesizer properties.** But if you're customizing further (e.g. Resources = S3 Bucket Name) – the way to set those values is to use **Synthesizer properties**:

```js
new MyStack(this, 'MyStack', {
  // stack properties
  synthesizer: new DefaultStackSynthesizer({
    qualifier: 'foo-backnd',
    fileAssetsBucketName: 'foo', // more likely e.g. 'cdk-${Qualifier}-assets-${AWS::AccountId}-${AWS::Region}'
    bucketPrefix: '',
  }),
});
```